# I want to return false in clicked time is greater than 200 ms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a youtube player. If user long presses on video, a option panel appears. I want to stop it. Is it possible that I write a query that if my click time is greater than 200ms, return false? I am currently using this code but this is not working.

```
$('video').on('click', function () {
    if(longpress) { // if detect hold, stop onclick function
        return false;
    };
});

$('video').on('mousedown', function () {
    longpress = false; //longpress is false initially
    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
    // your code here

    longpress = true; //if run hold function, longpress is true
    },300)
});

$('video').on('mouseup', function () {
    clearTimeout(pressTimer); //clear time on mouseup
});
```

Comment: add `var longpress = false, pressTimer;` before all your code

Comment: still not working and the issue is residing.

Comment: @Maxx they are globals so should not make a difference. Good practice would be to declare them.

Comment: You said you are testing it on mobile? Shouldn't you be using touch events?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to convert this function in my touch events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Maxx said, simply declare your variables first

```js
var longpress = false;
var pressTimer;
$('video').on('click', function() {
  console.log(longpress)
  if (longpress) { // if detect hold, stop onclick function
    return false;
  };
});

$('video').on('mousedown', function() {
  longpress = false; //longpress is false initially
  pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    // your code here

    longpress = true; //if run hold function, longpress is true
  }, 300)
});

$('video').on('mouseup', function() {
  clearTimeout(pressTimer); //clear time on mouseup
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);"></video>
```

Comment: not working. I am testing this on my mobile. So click, mouseup and mousedown are still applicable?

Comment: On most mobile devices a long click is interpreted as a right-mouse-button click.